# Convert String to Date in Groovy

Tags: date, groovy

I want to get the date time add minutes or hours, below code is working for me

```
def now = new Date();
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
   def new_date = now + 10.minutes;
}
```

Now the issue is the "10.minutes" is a variable come from other place, once I got it, it change to string.
So is there any method i can convert String (10.minutes) to like a object which i can use it to add with a date?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
def now = new Date()
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    String t = "10.minutes"
    def new_date = now + evaluate(t)
    println new_date
}
```